# Communication between groupcache's peers

Tags: http, caching, go

How do those [groupcache](https://github.com/golang/groupcache)'s peers communicate with each others? Through http?

I saw the example on the internets use HTTPPool to create a group of peers. Therefore, if I want to run up multiple server to serve the cache, must I use HTTPPool?
Is there any other way to create a group of peers, and enable them to communicate with each other?

I can correctly setup a single groupcache, but I'm confused about how to make it scalable through peers.

I'm not sure whether my understanding about HTTPPool and peers is right or not:

> Create a new HTTPPool and add peers into it.
>   Then groupcache will decide which peer should it ask for data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this source file](https://github.com/golang/groupcache/blob/master/http.go).

> How do those groupcache's peers communicate with each others? Through http?

Yes.

> must I use HTTPPool?

Yes.

> Is there any other way to create a group of peers, and enable them to communicate with each other?

Not with the implementation you referenced. You could fork it, though, and change the transport mechanism.

> I'm not sure whether my understanding about HTTPPool and peers is right or not

Use…

```
pool := groupcache.NewHTTPPool("http://localhost:8080") // Local address
```

…to create a new pool. Then add peers to it through…

```
pool.Set("http://example.net:8000", "http://another.net:8000") // Remote peer addresses
```